# Make ng-click call a certain method depending on a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-click` that I need to call one of 4 methods depending on a variable. I am displaying certain content on the page depending on something I call `{{vm.class}}`, which could be the word `Group` for example. Depending on if it's `Group` or not I want to call the method `createGroup()`. So if `{{vm.class}}` is equal to `Project` I'd want the `ng-click` to call `createProject()`. I'm not sure what is the best way to get this to happen. This is essentially what I'd want to happen though I know this doesn't work:

`data-ng-click=vm.create{{vm.class}}()` which would call `createGroup()` or `createProject()`

**EDIT**:

So something like:

`data-ng-click="create(vm.class)"`

and then:

```
function create(class){
    switch(class){
    case Group
         createGroup();
    }
    etc....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest keeping the logic in the controller. That is, `ngClick` should call a general function in the controller, that will decide which function to call based on other parameters.

HTML:

```
<any ng-click="vm.create()"></any>
```

Controller:

```
vm.create = function() {
  switch(vm.class) {
    //logic
  }
}
```

Comment: haha i ninja edit the same thing. Okay that's what I was thinking. I'll give you the +

Comment: Cool :) I think that's the best way

Answer (score 0):

> So something like:
>
> `data-ng-click="create(vm.class)"`

You can use right like this if add `create` method to `$scope`

or with a bit modification:

```
data-ng-click="vm.create(vm.class)"
```

and

```
vm.create = function create(class){
    switch(class){
        case Group
            createGroup();
        }
    etc....
}
```

OR even without common *create* function like this

```
data-ng-click="vm['create'+vm.class]()"
```

Comment: I think `vm['create'+vm.class]()` is a nice idea, but error prone

Comment: @yarons, what error? like when `vm` does not contain function _'create'+vm.class_?

Comment: @yarons, in this case just do nothing, so user don't see exception or something like